# Laravel 6 - Cannot change page language using Ajax call using Sessions

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I am trying to set language in a session and use it to change a form's language. I have an option to change the language at the top. But, even though I used ajax call, I am unable to change the language

What I am trying to do is :-
By default I am setting the language as 'eng' in the session. If the user changes the form language, then I make the session forget the langugage, and set the new language, say 'od'. But, it is not happening.

Here are the codes

**Blade**

```
@php

$formLang = Session::get('formLang');
@endphp
<select id="form_language" onchange="changeLang()">
 <option value='eng' @if($formLang == 'eng') selected @endif> English </option>
 <option value='od' @if($formLang == 'od') selected @endif> Od </option>

</select>
@if($formLang == 'eng')
 //Form in English
@else
/Form in od language
@endif

<script>
  function changeLang(){
    
    $.ajax({
          type : "POST",
          url :'{{ url("setFormLanguage") }}', 
          dataType : 'json', 
          data : {"lang":$('#form_language').val()},
          success : function(response) {
            if (response.message == "success") {
              console.log(response.lang);  --------->Still shows english
             
              
            }
          },
          error : function(data) {
            swal("Some Error Occured");
           // console.log(data);
          }
        })

  }
<script>
```

**Controller**

```
public function showForm(){
 $this->request->session()->put('formLang','eng');
return view('form');

}
public function setFormLanguage(Request $request){
   $lang=$request->lang;
   //echo $lang;exit;
         $this->request->session()->forget('formLang');
         $this->request->session()->put('formLang',$lang);
         $info['language']=$this->request->session()->get('formLang');
         $info['message']='success';
       
        return response()->json($info); 
 }
```

**web.php**

```
Route::match(['get', 'post'],'/setFormLanguage', 'LangController@setFormLanguage');
```

Am I doing wrong somewhere, or do I have to use two different forms for each language?

Answer (score 1):

```
@php
$formLang = Session::has('formLang') ?  Session::get('formLang') : 'eng';
@endphp
```

And Remove first Line Of Controller showForm function

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;
public function showForm(){
 //$this->request->session()->put('formLang','eng');//This line
 return view('form');
}

public function setFormLanguage(Request $request){
   $lang=$request->lang;
         Session::put('formLang',$lang);
          Session::save();
         $info['language']=Session::get('formLang');
         $info['message']='success';
       
        return response()->json($info); 
 }
```

Comment: Is this better, or the one where the user can choose a language just before entering the Form page?

Comment: Every time we have use default language and when some user change language it's will keep in session and we don't need reassign language code before showing form.

Comment: Using Ajax should be better, as you don't have to reload the page. In that case, if the form has been filled, then the contents wont vanish.